# How to decrypt AES CCM with salt on Windows?

Tags: openssl

I have an old file that contains some important information. I know the password, except I forgot how I generated it, and as a result don't know how to decrypt it.

Here it is (decoded from it's original base64):

```
{"iv":"HNpO0wJzMdTRl/2B0q4pPA==","v":1,"iter":1000,"ks":256,"ts":64,"mode":"ccm","adata":"","cipher":"aes","salt":"....", ct": "...."}
```

I can't figure out how to decode AES CCM. I've got `openssl` on Windows and Cygwin and neither seem to show support:

Windows:

```
Cipher commands (see the `enc' command for more details)
aes-128-cbc       aes-128-ecb       aes-192-cbc       aes-192-ecb
aes-256-cbc       aes-256-ecb       aria-128-cbc      aria-128-cfb
aria-128-cfb1     aria-128-cfb8     aria-128-ctr      aria-128-ecb
aria-128-ofb      aria-192-cbc      aria-192-cfb      aria-192-cfb1
aria-192-cfb8     aria-192-ctr      aria-192-ecb      aria-192-ofb
aria-256-cbc      aria-256-cfb      aria-256-cfb1     aria-256-cfb8
aria-256-ctr      aria-256-ecb      aria-256-ofb      base64
bf                bf-cbc            bf-cfb            bf-ecb
bf-ofb            camellia-128-cbc  camellia-128-ecb  camellia-192-cbc
camellia-192-ecb  camellia-256-cbc  camellia-256-ecb  cast
cast-cbc          cast5-cbc         cast5-cfb         cast5-ecb
cast5-ofb         des               des-cbc           des-cfb
des-ecb           des-ede           des-ede-cbc       des-ede-cfb
des-ede-ofb       des-ede3          des-ede3-cbc      des-ede3-cfb
des-ede3-ofb      des-ofb           des3              desx
idea              idea-cbc          idea-cfb          idea-ecb
idea-ofb          rc2               rc2-40-cbc        rc2-64-cbc
rc2-cbc           rc2-cfb           rc2-ecb           rc2-ofb
rc4               rc4-40            seed              seed-cbc
seed-cfb          seed-ecb          seed-ofb          sm4-cbc
sm4-cfb           sm4-ctr           sm4-ecb           sm4-ofb
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean you don't remember the name of the tool you generated it with?
If so, I think it is https://bitwiseshiftleft.github.io/sjcl/demo/

You can paste your JSON in the blue Ciphertext inputbox and your known password in the top left green Password inputbox, and your secret message should reveal itself when clicking on the blue decrypt arrow.